# Change the page title using a short code

Tags: wordpress

I am coding a plugin and I use a short code to render a page content. I want to change the page title. I used this:

```
// Change the title of the page of the charts to add the current month. 
add_filter('the_title', 'charts_title', 10, 2);
function charts_title($title, $id) { 
  $title .= ' ' . date('F Y');
  return $title;
}
```

But it does that for all the posts and pages. Can I do that only for the pages that contains the short code I created ? I tried to do that, but it doesn't work.

```
add_shortcode('charts-vote', 'charts_vote');
function charts_vote($atts) {
    // Add the filter only in the short code function callback.
    add_filter('the_title', 'charts_title', 10, 2);   

    // ... // 
    return $content;
}
```

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Your shortcode renders after the page header has printed. That is how shortcodes work, generally. That is, they render when `the_content` runs. This is going to be tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that the specifics of your set up may require checking for the Shortcode, but maybe a Custom Field could be used for that:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'charts_title_so_15312385', 10, 2 );

function charts_title_so_15312385( $title, $post_id ) 
{ 
    // Admin area, bail out
    if( is_admin() )
        return $title;

    // Custom field not set, bail out
    $mod_title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'mod_title', true );
    if( !$mod_title )
        return $title;

    // Ok, modify title
    $title .= ' ' . date( 'F Y' );
    return $title;
}
```

The Shortcode could even "talk" with the Custom Field for extended configurations.

For ease of use, you could make a [Custom Meta Box](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Badd_meta_box+%2Bsave_post+is%3Aanswer) or use a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

Comment: Glad to help, Monsieur Baptiste ;)